# How to loop through dictionary in jinja template

Tags: python, dictionary, set, jinja2

I have a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
{
 'Team Starwars': {'Luke Skywalker': {('Jedi', 100)}}
 'Team helloworld': {'Beginner': {('newbie', 100)}}
}
```

And now I want to iterate through the dictionary with jinja in a template.
I have tried somethings but can't iterate through it correctly.
The code I have now looks something like this:

```
  {% for team_name in team_resource %}
          {% for team, name in team_resource.items %}
                  {% for role, allocation in subrole %}
                    {% if forloop.counter0 != 0 %}<br>{% endif %}
                    {{role}} {{allocation}} %
           {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}
```

team_resource is the dictionary that I pass to the template, and in the first loop I can access the first part of the dictionary and print out like Team Starwars and Team helloworld', but can't access the rest of the dict.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `team_resource.items()` instead of `team_resource.items` to access dict items.

Comment: I don't know if I use a other version, but I can't use the items() without getting errors

Comment: I see. Try using the `iteritems()` method instead.

Comment: Note that `iteritems()` isn't in Python 3.

Comment: how do we access the dictionary objects after passing `items()` ?

Answer (score 1):

What you refer to as 'the rest of the dict' is actually the value of the key you managed to retrieve successfully.

Without testing, I believe the variable `name` is the one that holds the `{'Luke Skywalker': {('Jedi', 100)}` part of the dictionary in your example.